# Nonassociative quaternion algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, quaternions, paper-request, non-associative-algebras

I'm interested in nonassociative central simple algebras; I've found Lee and Waterhouse's article '[Maximal Orders in Nonassociative Quaternion Algebras](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002186939290077Y)', and this cites a previous article by Waterhouse, named 'Nonassociative Quaternion Algebras', published in Algebras, Groups, and Geometries 4 (1987). I've searched for the article and journal, but can't seem to find it anywhere. Where can I find that latter article?